# Colored collision C SFML

Tags: c, sfml

I was wondering if it is possible to set collisions using colours in C using the SFML library?
Because i am using a map with tiles and i don't know if it can work together.

Thank you!

Comment: SFML and C !? use SFML/C++ or SDL/C

Comment: Yes, there is a C version of SFML. And you can do things much easier with sfml than SDL :)

Comment: @MM. And just for the sake of completeness, you generally just have to replace the `::` by `_` to convert C++ SFML code to C code.

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't know it. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand, you use an image with two colors to define collision (say white is passable and black is blocked). And you want SFML to recognize it. Correct? `sf::Image` (`sfImage_createFromFile` and `sfImage_getPixelsPtr` if you are using CSFML) can read an image file and give you an array of pixels (colors). But SFML does not handle collision, it is a rendering library. Collisions must be part of your program's logic.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is simply use the sprite.setColor function like so

```
//Sets the sprite to purple
sprite.setColor(sf::Color(255,0,255));
```

Here is the documentation
http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#a14def44da6437bfea20c4df5e71aba4c and here is the sf::Color documentation http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Color.php

Answer (score 0):

Handling collisions must be something that you **define in your code**.
If you're working with a tile map, it should keep values for each tile, defining which type of cell it is.

With those values you can work inside your program and do **drawing and logic separately**, but both based on tile map info.

In one hand, you must draw your tiles with a color corresponding with the tile value. This process is done to draw each frame, so you **shouldn't charge** it with complex logic (as collisions are)

On the other hand, you must check if other entities (player, projectiles, etc) are colliding with the tiles one by one, preferably only when needed (called by an event, as user input, for example)